# Regex split with comma but not in Square Brackets and not in Brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, split

i have this string

```
StudentInfo[id] as stu_id, StudentInfo[ssn] as stu_ssn, verylong.library.path.ScoreInfo[min_points, max_points] as sinfo, left_join((id),(customer_id)), reference.dilino[(greed,greed)], reference.dilino2[dilino], reference.dilino3[reference.dilino4[(kaktus,kaktus2)],reference.dilino5[(kaktus3,kaktus4)]], reference.dilino6[reference.dilino4[(kaktus,kaktus2),dilino]
```

and i want split to this

```
StudentInfo[id] as stu_id
StudentInfo[ssn] as stu_ssn
verylong.library.path.ScoreInfo[min_points, max_points] as sinfo
left_join((id),(customer_id))
reference.dilino[(greed,greed)]
reference.dilino2[dilino]
reference.dilino3[reference.dilino4[(kaktus,kaktus2)]
reference.dilino5[(kaktus3,kaktus4)]]
reference.dilino6[reference.dilino4[(kaktus,kaktus2),dilino]
```

i have now this regex

```
/,(?=[^\]]*(?:\[)|[^\)]*(?:\()|$)/gm
```

but it's not good :( can you help me?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: this is in file and i must parse to array for UI

Comment: Also, why do you want to split on the comma between the third-to-last and the second-to-last item? Looks like there shouldn't be a split because of the nested brackets. And the last item doesn't have correctly balanced brackets. If that's really your input, it's a mess.

Comment: You cannot parse programming languages with regexes. Use a parser such as https://github.com/steveyen/sqld3

Comment: yes the last ] is missing sorry wrong copy paste... i want split with comma not in not in Square Brackets and not in Brackets, so simple but not simple regex :(

Comment: @TimPietzcker this is not a SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?![^)(]*\([^)(]*?\)\)),(?![^\[]*\])
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/8

Comment: -1: no explanation, more over it seems "hacked" together. See [it failing](http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/9). Hint: to do this *properly*, you will need a more powerful engine like PCRE or .NET, you will need recursion because of the nested nature.

Comment: @HamZa - The OP can debug the regex (the link). The regex itself isn't simple.  I don't think you should be down-voting (I agree if you don't up-vote) because there is no explanation..

Comment: there is no simple way? to ignore comma in [ ( ) ] ?

Comment: @TheLostMind "The regex itself isn't simple", well if it isn't simple then it's another reason to actually explain in detail how the regex works. I downvoted because it is hacked together and he didn't even warn the OP of possible problems he might encounter when the structure gets more nested.

Comment: @Kepro no there is not. You can't do it reliably with regex in JavaScript and in other regex engines it gets quite complicated. In JavaScript you might write your own parser but I wonder if that's worth the time.

Comment: -1, this answer is essentially useless for anyone but the OP (and in a matter of fact for them too).

Comment: @georg - The link provides the explanation. Any explanation here would just be redundant.

Comment: @georg in javascript there is no better option to do this.Atleast this unblock the OP.There is no `\K` or something to create a more generralised regex.

Comment: @TheLostMind: the problem is not the missing explanation (I'm actually fine with code-only answers), but that this solution only "works" for the given particular input and isn't going to be helpful for anyone else.

Comment: @georg - Yes, the given code is *specific* to the OP's question and generally, I would agree with you on this. But this isn't some java / python question that has to be useful to others. Infact most regex questions are usually useless to others.

Comment: @vks: if you're willing to edit your answer and turn it into something like "here's the regex that works for your input (code) but it will fail for the general case (example). In Net/PCRE you could use (code) to overcome this, but in JS you have to (suggested workaround)" - I'll be happy to revoke my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regex like this : `,(?=[\s\w](?!\w+[\)\]]))`
[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/xI1lA1/4)