# How to convert string of Array of Arrays into a Javascript array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, regex

I get a string from an end point, the string will be in any of the forms as shown below

Input:

First Form

```
Option1[opt1,opt4,opt8,opt7],Option5[opt2,opt3],Option6[opt5,opt6]
```

**Expected output**:

```
[ 
  Option1[opt1,opt4,opt8,opt7],
  Option5[opt2,opt3], 
  Option6[opt5,opt6]
]
```

or

```
Option1[1,4,8,7],Option5[2,3],Option6[5,6]
```

**Expected output**:

```
[ 
  Option1[1,4,8,7],
  Option5[2,3], 
  Option6[5,6]
]
```

Second Form

```
Option1[opt1],Option5[opt2],Option6[opt6]
```

**Expected output**:

```
[ 
  Option1[opt1],
  Option5[opt2], 
  Option6[opt5]
]
```

or

```
Option1[1],Option5[2],Option6[6]
```

**Expected output**:

```
[ 
  Option1[1],
  Option5[2], 
  Option6[5]
]
```

Third Form

```
Option1,Option5,Option6 or Item1,Item2,Item3 or abc1,xyz2,ccc3
```

Expected output

```
[ 
  Option1,
  Option5, 
  Option6
]
```

for the Second and Third forms

```
.split(',')
```

works and returns expected array but here i am facing challenge with First form, 
looking for some options (reg exp) that can consider `,` after `]`.

**Note**: Sorry for making changes in the question as i see input coming from endpoint is changing, but now i will not make any more edits for the inputs in the question

Comment: Please explain the expected output, it is not valid JS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988636/regex-split-with-comma-but-not-in-square-brackets-and-not-in-brackets

Comment: Your "expected output", aside from not being valid JS, doesn't seem to cover the third input format.

Answer (score 2):

Split comma "," followed by upper case "O"

```
str.split(/,(?=O)/)
```

Comment: Thanks @guest271314 that worked if string contains Optionsxx what if it has different value like my updated question for Third form `Option1,Option5,Option6 or Item1,Item2,Item3 or abc1,xyz2,ccc3`

Comment: @Sri If letter character begins matching pattern you can use `RegExp` `/,(?=[a-z])/i` to match comma `,` followed by a-z case insensitive `var str = "Option1[1,4,8,7],Option5[2,3],Option6[5,6],abc1,xyz2,ccc3,Item1,Item2,Item3"; var res = str.split(/,(?=[a-z])/i); console.log(res);`

Comment: I just noticed that the input is having another form which has strings with in the array i.e `Option1[opt1,opt4,opt8,opt7],Option5[opt2,opt3],Option6[opt5,opt6]` in that case it is almost behaving like `.split(',')`

Comment: You have now changed requirement twice. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i mean if the given string is `Option1[opt1,opt4,opt8,opt7],Option5[opt2,opt3],Option6[opt5‌​,opt6]` i am getting the output as `["Option1[opt1","opt4","opt8","opt7]","Option5[opt2","opt3]","Option6[opt5‌​","opt6]"]` for your suggested answer. The length of the result array is supposed to be 3 but it is 8

Comment: sorry  @guest271314 i just noticed that it is also one of the form of input string coming from end point

Comment: Yes, you have changed expected input twice from original question

Comment: i agree @guest271314, so is it possible to split if the input comes in that way

Comment: It should be possible by adjusting RegExp or using multiple RegExp patterns

Answer (score 0):

Try with below, using regex:

```js
var check1 = 'Option1[1,4,8,7],Option5[2,3],Option6[5,6]';
var check2 = 'Option1[1],Option5[2],Option6[6]';
var check3 = 'Item1,Item2,Item3';

var regex = /\s*,\s*(?![^\[\]]*\])/g;

var arr1 = check1.split(regex);
var arr2 = check2.split(regex);
var arr3 = check3.split(regex);

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```