# Split string with regex skipping brackets []

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and need to split it by whitespace but if there would be some words inside brackets I need to skip it.

For example,

```
input: 'tree car[tesla BMW] cat color[yellow blue] dog'

output: ['tree', 'car[tesla BMW]', 'cat', 'color[yellow blue]', 'dog']
```

if I use simple `.split(' ')` it would go inside brackets and return an incorrect result.

Also, I've tried to write a regex, but unsuccessfully :(

My last regex looks like this `.split(/(?:(?<=\[).+?(?=\])| )+/)` and return `["tree", "car[", "]", "cat", "color[", "]", "dog"]`

Would be really grateful for any help

Comment: /\w+(?:\[.+?])?/g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easier with `match`:

```js
input = 'tree car[tesla BMW] cat xml:cat xml:color[yellow blue] dog'

output = input.match(/[^[\]\s]+(\[.+?\])?/g)

console.log(output)
```

With `split` you need a lookahead like this:

```js
input = 'tree car[tesla BMW] cat color[yellow blue] dog'

output = input.split(/ (?![^[]*\])/)

console.log(output)
```

Both snippets only work if brackets are not nested, otherwise you'd need a parser rather than a regexp.

Comment: As for the first regex with `.match()` it works with an issue if we have a string with `:` like `tree:test car[tesla BMW]` it returns `["tree", "test", "car[tesla BMW]"]`, but `.split()` works as expected! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @MarkMark: first snippet fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You could split on a space asserting to the right 1 or more non whitespace chars except for square brackets and optionally match from an opening till closing square bracket followed by a whitespace boundary at the right.

```
[ ](?=[^\][\s]+(?:\[[^\][]*])?(?!\S))
```

**Explanation**

- `[ ]` Match a space (square brackets only for clarity)
- `(?=` Postive lookahead

  - `[^\][\s]+` Match 1+ times any char except `]` `[` or a whitespace char
  - `(?:\[[^\][]*])?` Optinally match from `[...]`
  - `(?!\S)` A whitespace boundary to the right
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uU5lTm/1)

```js
const regex = / (?=[^\][\s]+(?:\[[^\][]*])?(?!\S))/g;
[
  "tree car[tesla BMW] cat color[yellow blue] dog",
  "tree car[tesla BMW] cat xml:cat xml:color[yellow blue] dog",
  "tree:test car[tesla BMW]",
  "tree car[tesla BMW] cat color yellow blue] dog",
  "tree car[tesla BMW] cat color[yellow blue dog"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.split(regex)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one regex find all option:

```js
var input = 'tree car[tesla BMW] cat color[yellow blue] dog';
var matches = input.match(/\[.*?\]|[ ]|\b\w+\b/g);
var output = [];
var idx1 = 0;
var idx2 = 0;

do {
    if (matches[idx1] === " ") {
        ++idx1;
        continue;
    }

    do {
        output[idx2] = output[idx2] ? output[idx2] + matches[idx1] : matches[idx1];
        ++idx1;
    } while(matches[idx1] != " " && idx1 < matches.length);
    ++idx2;
} while(idx1 < matches.length);

console.log(output);
```

For an explanation of the regex, we deal with the `[...]` terms which might have spaces by eagerly trying to match them first.  Next, we look for space separators, and finally we look for standalone words.  Here is the regex:

```regex
\[.*?\]   find a [...] term
|         OR
[ ]       find a space
|         OR
\b\w+\b   find a word
```

This gives us the following intermediate array:

```
["tree", " ", "car", "[tesla BMW]", " ", "cat", " ", "color", "[yellow blue]", " ", "dog"]
```

Then we iterate and join together all non space entries in an output array, using the actual spaces to indicate where the real separations should be happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist to use regex I recommend you to watch [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988636/regex-split-with-comma-but-not-in-square-brackets-and-not-in-brackets) page.
The writer split by comma but I believe you smart enough to change it to `space`