# Java regular expression to split a string by dashes positioned outside of double curly braces

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter

I have some strings that I want to separate based on dashes but only if dashes exist outside of double curly braces like below:

{{abc-def}}-123-benefit-{{ghi}} should break into {{abc-def}}, 123, benefit, {{ghi}}

abc-{{123-def}}-benefit-{{ghi}} should break into abc, {{123-def}}, benefit, {{ghi}}

I am trying to use regex to do that, but not able to get it done since I am novice with Regex. Based on some of the answers I could research, I tried following piece, but didn't get expected output:

```
String regex = "-(?!\\{\\{^\\{\\{\\}\\}*\\}\\})";
String newRegex = "-(?:[^,\"]|\"[^\"]*\")+-";
String abc = "{{abc-def}}-123-benefit-{{def}}";
String[] output1 = abc.split(regex);
String[] output2 = abc.split(newRegex);
```

Getting output1 as

```
["{{abc", "def}}", "123", "benefit", "{{def}}"]
```

and output2 as

```
["{{abc", "{{def}}"]
```

Expected output is

```
["{{abc-def}}", "123", "benefit", "{{def}}"]
```

Comment: [This is close to a dup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67637203/1270789), but is for JavaScript instead; it should be easy to adapt into an answer but I don't have time right now.

Comment: Even though some find regex convenient, I find complicated regex hard to maintain, and probably should be avoided.  A simple parser, just a loop that iterates over the string, would be easy to implement and understand for a later maintainer.

Comment: @markspace - Indeed.  Increment counter on char='{', decrement on char='}', split on counter=0 & char='-'.  Done.

Answer (score 1):

You could match the regular expression

```
(?:\{\{.*?\}\}|[^{}\-]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/drR4nB/1)

The expression could be broken down as follow.

```
(?:         begin a non-capture group
  \{\{      match literal
  .*?       match zero or more chars other than line terminators, lazily
  \}\}      match literal
|           or
  [^{}\-]+  match one or more characters other than '{', '}' or '-'
)           end non-capture group
```

Comment: thanks for the response @Cary, I see in the demo it is working as expected but when I do
`
abc.split(regex)
`

I am getting the output as
`
["", "-", "-", "-"]
`

Comment: With this regex you need to match, not split. See the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will be simpler if you use `matcher` instead of `split`. Note that in your first regex, the `^` functions as a start of input anchor, so that will never match.

With `matcher` you can use this regex:

```
\{\{.*?\}\}|[^-]+
```

In code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

// ...

        String regex = "\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}|[^-]+";
        String abc = "{{abc-def}}-123-benefit-{{def}}";
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(abc);
        while (m.find()) {
            output.add(m.group());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a non-answer, but it's taken you an hour to get a regex answer, and this took me 20 minutes including some light testing and comments.  It's a bit more complicated than I thought, though perhaps that could be improved.

I've added some light comments to indicate what I'm doing.  Adding some Javadoc to the `parse()` method would also make it more readable.

If you find it helpful, feel free to copy.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Brenden
 */
public class ParseDashBrace {
   
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      List<String> test1 = parse( "{{abc-def}}-123-benefit-{{ghi}}" );
      System.out.println( "Test1 " + test1 );
      List<String> test2 = parse( "abc-{{123-def}}-benefit-{{ghi}}" );
      System.out.println( "Test2 " + test2 );
   }
   
   static List<String> parse( String line ) {
      ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
      boolean inBrace = false;
      boolean firstBrace = false;
      int start = 0; 
      int end = 0;
      // parse the string, split on - and {{}}
      for( ; end < line.length(); end++ ) {
         char c = line.charAt( end );
         if( !inBrace ) {
            // if we are not inside braces, then we look for "-"
            if( c == '-' ) {
               if( start != end )
                  tokens.add( line.substring( start, end) );
               start = end+1;
            } else if( c == '{' ) {
               // we also need to know when we find a brace and are inside
               inBrace = true;
            }
         } else {
            if( c == '}' ) {
               if( firstBrace ) {
                  // we had a first brace and now we found another, two braces total
                  tokens.add( line.substring( start, end+1 ) );
                  start = end+1;
                  firstBrace = false;
                  inBrace = false;
               } else {
                  // this is just the first end brace, flag it, wait for next one
                  firstBrace = true;
               }
            }
         }
      }
      if( start != end ) 
         tokens.add( line.substring( start, end ) );
      return tokens;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

Used regex:

```
"(?<!\\{\\{\\w{1,100})-"
```

See regex in context and test-bench, below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = "{{abc-def}}-123-benefit-{{ghi}}";
    String input2 = "abc-{{123-def}}-benefit-{{ghi}}";

    String regex = "(?<!\\{\\{\\w{1,100})-";

    System.out.println("Result of input1: " + Arrays.asList(input1.split(regex)));
    System.out.println("Result of input2: " + Arrays.asList(input2.split(regex)));
}
```

Output:

```
Result of input1: [{{abc-def}}, 123, benefit, {{ghi}}]
Result of input2: [abc, {{123-def}}, benefit, {{ghi}}]
```

Comment:

```
Used Pattern:
(?<!X)  X, via zero-width negative lookbehind
```

Read more about Pattern here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Other tools for testing regex: https://regex101.com/